# Simultaneous running cron jobs records processing mix

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm struggling with multiple same time lunched cronjobes same record process issue

*Intro*

- I have db table where is present 100+ customers
- For each customer i have to run some script via cronjobe per each 5 minutes
- Cronjobe takes each customer from db immediately update last used timestamp so that next cron will select 5 minutes older processed next record
- Cronjobe processing takes approx 30second
- So it mean to process all 100 customers during required 5 minutes i will need to have approx 10 simulations cron jobes wokring
- all cron's defined as: * * * * * php cron.php (so each 1 minute lunched 10 cronjobes)
- The cron dose some network lookup to that customer ip and log it to log database it should happend for each customer during each 5 minutes as later i will draw chart based on logs for each customer
- code is written in PHP, DB is MySql

**The problem is when that 10 cronjobes starts at the same time randomly happens that 2 cronjobes selected same customer from database to process**

So it mean 2 crons are start at alsmost same time (micro seconds diffarance)
both are select at same time last unprocessed row (e.g. id:17) from database then update same id17 in database 3-dth lunched cronjobe already took id:18.
But i need that each coronjobe will take unique next record from database not same

`As a workaround i tried to add random sleep(rand(1,10)) delay at beginning of cron.php but don't help mutch, random duplication still happens cause cron continuously selects last unprocessed next customer which sometime matches with another cornjobe next customer select at same time`

Is there any solutions present for this situation ???

Comment: You could assign each customer to one of the ten cron jobs, permanently. That way a customer is always handled by the same job, and no collisions can occur. Apart from such a basic solution: This all sounds very weird. Do you really need to expend 30 seconds processing times with each customer every 5 minutes? This makes me wonder what this is all about. For better solutions it would be nice to have an idea, and I am also just curious.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for comment, actually and customers and crons count will increase continuously and it would be very hard to optimally assign each customer to its personal cornjobe. The cron dose some network lookup to that customer ip and log it to log database it should happend for each customer during each 5 minutes as later i will draw chart based on logs - *the idea is to have many cronjobes which will randomly select last unprocessed customer and process*

Comment: It's not hard to assign customers to cron jobs. Suppose you have 10 jobs, numbered 0 to 9, and 200 customers, with unique ID's 0 to 199. You can assign customers like this: `$jobNo = $customerID % 10;`. Similarly, an cron job can simply select every tenth customer. This is not hard to do.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware aha i see thanks, good approach select by %id mask, but in this case if admin let say removed all customers which match cron with mask %5 then that 5-th cronjobe will have less work to do then oters (instead he can help others)  and solution will be again not optimal but Yes we will avoid duplication

Comment: Yes, deleted customers will pose a slight challenge, but I think this can be overcome. This basic idea remains the same: Make it so that a customer can never be selected by multiple cron jobs.

Comment: *The problem is when that 10 cronjobes starts at the same time randomly happens that 2 cronjobes selected same customer from database to process* You must assign not only current timestamp to some `processedAt` column but additionally assign the value returned by `CONNECTION_ID()` MySQL function to additional column (like `processedBy`). After assigning (reserve for self) the job must check that the value of this connection ID is equal to self one (i.e. none concurrent job have re-reserved this row). PS. I recommend you use MySQL's built-in Event Scheduler, not external Cron scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you seek is **collaborative locking**. The customer must be marked "locked" by some job, and no script must choose a customer that is locked by another script.

Also, you must do this in such a way that no two jobs choose the same customer to acquire.

In MySQL you can do:

```
$me = getmypid();
$conn->execute("SELECT GET_LOCK('choosing', 5) AS okay");
// Check the returned value of okay. If it is not 1, exit() immediately.
// choose some customer in some way. The smallest Id with OwnedByPid=0 for example. The query should be fast enough to run in under 5 seconds.
$conn->execute("UPDATE customers SET OwnedByPid={$me} WHERE id={$custId};");
$conn->execute("SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('choosing'");
//

// Do your work

$conn->execute("SELECT GET_LOCK('choosing', 5)");
$conn->execute("UPDATE customers SET OwnedByPid=0 WHERE OwnedByPid={$me};");
$conn->execute("SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('choosing')");
```

Then, periodically - when no scripts are running - release the customers that might be marked by a script that crashed:

```
$conn->execute("UPDATE customers SET OwnedByPid=0;");
```

Or you can add another column, OwningStart, set it to NOW() when you take ownership, so you can check when OwningStart is older than 30 seconds and clear it. Or mark it as free:

```
SELECT MIN(Id) FROM customers WHERE OwnedByPid=0 OR OwningStart < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE;
```

Comment: Thank you, look like the solution which i'm looking for ! Just one question SELECT GET_LOCK('choosing', 5)  means if anoter cron will run same SELECT GET_LOCK('choosing', 5) he will get null result and it mean i will need to have some kind of infinite loop in that cron which will continuously check "choosing" and once it released do its own lock and take a record right ?

Comment: No, GET_LOCK is blocking (up to the requested 5 seconds). In that time, which is plenty to run the query to select the customer ID, all other cron jobs running GET_LOCK will be stopped and waiting. So they will all remain queued.

If the first section is executed in 0.01 seconds or less, as is likely, then 10 jobs will at the most wait for an additional piddling tenth of a second.